# Can I wholly replace a graphic with another one?

Tags: support, markdown, images

I have an image that I use over and over... I am savvy to how SE stores images on Imgur.  So whenever I insert it, I find the URL of the image `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh0yO.png`, and tell "post image" that I have a URL.  The SE platform is smart enough to realize it's already an `i.stack.imgur` image, so it doesn't copy it.

I use that in a bunch of locations, and it has errata. I'd like to fix them all without ferreting out every Q&A I ever used it on, and editing each post.

Is there a way to replace `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh0yO.png` with my revised image, so shows up everywhere the old image used to?

Comment: That's...kind of intentional, to ensure that whenever an image is updated, it triggers an edit in Stack Exchange's system.

Comment: Silent "unclear what you're asking" closevoters: what's unclear?

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible. I don't even think imgur stores which Stack Exchange user uploaded the image, so it would not be able to prevent somebody else 'hijacking' your image.

If you use an image quite often and expect errata, you should consider hosting it yourself, or use a platform that allows editing (I don't know of any, I haven't been in your position.)

Answer (score 3):

Imgur doesn't allow editing images. If you want to replace it, you have to delete the old one and upload a new one, giving it a new identifier. The same probably applies to Stack Imgur, especially considering we're given very little control over uploading to it.

If you want to replace an image in all your posts with it, you need to upload a new image and edit all posts. If you have troubles finding all posts, you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com).

Please note that you aren't limited to Stack Imgur. You can upload images to normal Imgur (when you're authorized, you have higher file size limit, for example) or on some host that allows editing. You can insert any image using `![](url)` syntax.